# parcolumns, Vertical Misalignment of Columns

Tags: vertical-alignment, parcolumns

The columns produced by parcolumns are not vertically aligned. Why, and how can this be fixed *using the parcolumns package as intended*?

I have found similar questions with answers that I find unsuitable here:

1. [vspace has no effect in parcolumns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51041/vspace-has-no-effect-in-parcolumns)
2. [Parcolumns: Matching height of two adjacent columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75012/parcolumns-matching-height-of-two-adjacent-columns)

Question (2) is essentially the same; however, I do not consider the accepted answer satisfactory.

Thanks to the comments below, the following code produces vertically aligned columns.

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}

\usepackage{parcolumns}

\begin{document}

\begin{parcolumns}{2}
\colchunk{%
\section{Introduction}\null}
\colchunk{%
\section{Einf{\"u}hrung}\null}
\end{parcolumns}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `\null` (or `\mbox{}`) after each section so they both have content following them, and they'll be aligned.